# using group by in linq nested list c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am using a linq c# query to group distict combination based on Library and books.
I have list of Libraries and list of Books inside each library
Input XML:

```
<Libraries>
    <LibraryCode value="1">test</LibraryCode>
    <LibraryArea>XYZ</LibraryArea>
    <Books BookID="Book_ID1">
        <BookName>Name1</BookName>
        <BookCode code="1">Code1</BookCode>
    </Books>
    <Books BookID="Book_ID2">
        <BookName>Name2</BookName>
        <BookCode code="1">Code1</BookCode>
    </Books>
</Libraries>

<Libraries>
    <LibraryCode value="2">test</LibraryCode>
    <LibraryArea>ABC</LibraryArea>
    <Books BookID="Book_ID1">
        <BookName>Name1</BookName>
        <BookCode code="1">Code1</BookCode>
    </Books>
    <Books BookID="Book_ID2">
        <BookName>Name2</BookName>
        <BookCode code="1">Code1</BookCode>
    </Books>
</Libraries>

<Libraries>
    <LibraryCode value="3">test</LibraryCode>
    <LibraryArea>ABC</LibraryArea>
    <Books BookID="Book_ID3">
        <BookName>Name3</BookName>
        <BookCode code="3">Code3</BookCode>
    </Books>
</Libraries>

<Libraries>
    <LibraryCode value="4">test</LibraryCode>
    <LibraryArea>ABC</LibraryArea>
    <Books BookID="Book_ID3">
        <BookName>Name3</BookName>
        <BookCode code="3">Code3</BookCode>
    </Books>
</Libraries>

<Libraries>
    <LibraryCode value="5">test</LibraryCode>
    <LibraryArea>ABC</LibraryArea>
    <Books BookID="Book_ID5">
        <BookName>Name5</BookName>
        <BookCode code="5">Code5</BookCode>
    </Books>
</Libraries>
```

Expected XML:

```
<Libraries>
    <LibraryCode value="1">test</LibraryCode>
    <LibraryArea>XYZ</LibraryArea>
    <Books BookID="Book_ID1">
        <BookName>Name1</BookName>
        <BookCode code="1">Code1</BookCode>
    </Books>
    <Books BookID="Book_ID2">
        <BookName>Name2</BookName>
        <BookCode code="1">Code1</BookCode>
    </Books>
</Libraries>

<Libraries>
    <LibraryCode value="3">test</LibraryCode>
    <LibraryArea>ABC</LibraryArea>
    <Books BookID="Book_ID3">
        <BookName>Name3</BookName>
        <BookCode code="3">Code1</BookCode>
    </Books>
</Libraries>

<Libraries>
    <LibraryCode value="5">test</LibraryCode>
    <LibraryArea>ABC</LibraryArea>
    <Books BookID="Book_ID5">
        <BookName>Name5</BookName>
        <BookCode code="5">Code1</BookCode>
    </Books>
</Libraries>
```

Please note that the books combination in 1st record and 2nd record are same i.e with LibraryCode value'1' and '2'.Though it could be distict,I require only one Library record('1' or '2') based on **BookID** as the book records are same for 1st and 2nd record
Similarly for the 4th and 5th records,I need only one and I require the 5th library record as it is a different combination with Library and Books.
Here Library and Books are lists.
Code I am using

```
var result= libraries.GroupBy(x=>x.Books.Select(s=>s.BookID)).Select(grp=>grp.ToList()).ToList();
```

This seems not working.
Any help would be much appreciated .
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Almost all reference types are compared by reference by default, so either a custom comparer would be needed to compare by value(s), or group by type that is compared by value :

```
libraries.GroupBy(l => string.Join(",", l.Books.Select(b => b.BookID)))
```

Comment: This returns 1 count but the resultview shows all 5 libraries.It should return the whole library list

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you compare two collections of book ids by reference. I guess the custom comparer would be more appropriate in this case, you should add it as a second parameter after group by key selector.

```
libraries.GroupBy(x=>x.Books.Select(s=>s.BookID), new BookIdsComparer ())

public class BookIdsComparer : IEqualityComparer<IEnumerable<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(IEnumerable<string> bookIds1, IEnumerable<string> bookIds2)
    {
        return bookIds1.Count() == bookIds2.Count() 
            && bookIds1.Intersect(bookIds2).Count() == bookIds1.Count();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(IEnumerable<string> bookIds)
    {
        var result = 1;
        foreach (var bookId in bookIds)
        {
            result ^= bookId.GetHashCode();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```